# Pass data via on click from child component to parent component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and trying to pass data (director, nonDirector) from my child functional component to a parent class component.

My code is below, what do I need to do to make it work?

**Class parent component**

```
export default class ProfileEditor extends React.Component<IProfileEditorProps, IProfileEditorState> {
    
      constructor(props: IProfileEditorProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: null,
        }
         this.updateProfile = this.updateProfile.bind(this);
      }

    public updateProfile(director, nonDirector) {

        console.log('hello', director, nonDirector);

     }

      <MultiSelect
        options={ profile?.Declarations.length == 0 ? countries : this.combineProfileAndCountrys() }   
        updateProfile={updateProfile()}
      />
```

**Child functional component**

```
export const MultiSelect = ({ options, updateProfile }) => { 

const [nonDirector, setNonDirector] = React.useState();
const [director, setDirector] = React.useState();

<PrimaryButton text='Save' onClick={ updateProfile(nonDirector, director) } />
    </Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your parent component you shouldn't be calling the function in the `onClick` handler. You want to pass the *reference* to the function to it instead.

```
updateProfile={updateProfile}
```

A similar issue is occurring in your child component. You don't want to call the function and have the results of it returned to the handler, you want to assign a function to the handler that can then call the `updateProfile` function when its triggered.

```
onClick={() => updateProfile(nonDirector, director)}
```